# How to install APACHE in openshift?

Tags: apache, openshift, redhat, apr

Now when i try to install apache it gives error

```
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library..
```

APR not found..

How to install APR in openshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  If you just want to run a static html site, then just use one of the php cartridges, and it will service static content just fine.  Otherwise it might help to explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: thanks for reply mate.
I am trying to install bugzilla there.
So i need perl,mysql and apache.
When i choose perl cartridge and then mysql i am not able choose Apache cartridge .
So i want to install apache manually..

Comment: The perl cartridge uses apache by default, you should not need to install apache manually.

Comment: what if i want to use openshift as a file server or a server to have few images along with public path of those images to be used in my jsp

Comment: The php cartridge does not work out of the box for static HTML files as Apache would. Try to move  a folder with static html files, then try to render them in the browser. Result = 0